# Where is the data created from my form going?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I just created a form for the first time and have some questions regarding the process and where the data is going.

Here are my models, views, forms, urls, and templates files;

**The model from models.py:**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.SlugField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    mobile = models.SlugField(max_length=20)
    income = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=INCOME_CHOICES)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)
    home_district = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=DISTRICT_CHOICES)
    family_spending = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=FAMILY_SPENDING_CHOICES)
    children_spending = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CHILDREN_SPENDING_CHOICES)   
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField('Birthday', blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
def create_a_member_form(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MemberForm(request.POST)
    if form is valid():
      member_form = form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/complete/')
  else:
    form = MemberForm()
  return render(request, 'member_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from .models import Member
from django import forms 

class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^member_form/$', views.create_a_member_form, name='member_form')
]
```

**The template (member_form.html):**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<form action="/admin/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to know:

- In the template, what does the /admin/ in `<form action="/admin/" method="post">` represent? It's where the page redirects to after I click 'Submit', right?
- Does the `name='member_form'` in urls.py represent the name of the HTML template the URL will match to, in thise case member_form.html?
- Where is the data created from the form going? I've tried creating Member objects using the form but the new objects do not show up in my admin site under Members (while existing ones do). How do I make sure the objects created from this form do show up in my Admin site under Members?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No, it's the name you use in a `{% url %}` tag if you want to generate a link pointing at that URL. The template is determined by the view itself (in `render(request, 'member_form.html',...)`).
3. It's not going anywhere, because your view is posting to /admin/ instead of /member_form/; /admin/ is the index of the admin site which has no code to actually accept your form data.

Note that 1 is basic HTML, and 2 and 3 are basic Django concepts which are covered in the tutorial; you should go and read that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean my view is posting to /admin/ instead of /member_form/?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is unclear. As you yourself said in point 1, the action attribute represents the place the form submits the data to. You need to make it so that the form sends the data to the view that is expecting it, not some other random URL.

Comment: What I meant by 'redirect' was not in terms of where the data was going, but where the page refreshes to after 'Submit'. But I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Again, what happens afterwards is controlled by the view, when you do `return HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: I changed /admin/ to /member_form/ in the template, but when I click 'Submit' I get a page not found error even though I've mapped  url(r'^member_form/$', views.create_a_member_form, name='member_form') in urls.py :/

Comment: Is that your root urls.py, or is it being included by another one? In any case, it's best practice to use the `{% url %}` tag as I mentioned above: `form action="{% url 'member_form' %}"`.

Comment: I'm now getting a NameError at /expcore/member_form/, saying that "global name 'valid' is not defined" in my views.py, where I use valid(). I tried adding `from django.core import validators` but I still get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: `if form.is_valid():`

Comment: That's what I have, but it still says "global name 'valid' is not defined" in that very line.

Comment: No that is not what you have. You have `if form is valid()` which is not at all the same as `if form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Sorry this took so long, but I really appreciate the help.